# react-native run-android build successful but not working

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, window

I'm a developer developing react-native using VSC on Windows. The build succeeds, but it turns out not to run

I had this error message before this problem occurred.

A problem occurred configuring project ': app'.

> The SDK directory 'D: \ Merryholiday \ asd \ android \ ' does not exist.

But when I turn on Android Studio, this error message goes away.
The react-native run-android command printed BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

But unfortunately in the next line
Access is denied.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUG0g.png)
With only a message, the app is installed on the device, but it doesn't run. When I run it, I see the make sure blabla error screen that appears when there is no node server.

This problem eliminated my two days.
I want to get help.

Ps. Note that project asd is a new project for testing. If you look at the existing project and test project, I guess it might be Java configuration, but ... I am suffering because there is no proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must add ***local.properties*** file to android folder. The contents of the sample file should be as follows.

sdk.dir=/home/Merryholiday/Android/Sdk

Comment: This solution didn't work for me.
The local.properties file already exists.
The contents of the file are the same as the solution.